# Supply password to HSQLDB SqlTool in a script

Tags: hsqldb

I am running an HSQLDB instance in server mode as a systemd service. To shut it down, I issue the following command:

```
java -cp $CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/hsqldbutil.jar:/usr/share/java/hsqldb.jar "org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlTool" --inlineRc=url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/$DB_NAME,user=SA,password=`cat ~/SA.pwd` --sql="SHUTDOWN;"
```

As one can see in the command, I connect as user SA with a password read from a file (which only that particular user can read), and specify both in the JDBC URL.

This works as long as SA has an empty password and I just supply `password=` in the command.

However, if SA has a real password and I supply it here, this fails with the error message:

> 'password' element must have empty value. For non-empty password, give no password element and you will be prompted for the value.

Is there any way to supply the password in a non-interactive way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you use a `sqltool.rc` file instead of `--inline-rc`. Place a file with the following contents in the home folder of the account which will be issuing the stop command:

```
urlid my-server
url jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/db_name
username SA
password CorrectHorseBatteryStaple
```

Then modify the command line as follows:

```
java -cp $CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/hsqldbutil.jar:/usr/share/java/hsqldb.jar "org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlTool" --sql="SHUTDOWN;" my-server
```

Where:

- `my-server` is an arbitrary identifier that you define in `sqltool.rc` and quote in the command line invocation of SqlTool
- `db_name` is the database name assigned at startup
- `CorrectHorseBatteryStaple` is the SA password (as currently stored in `~/SA.pwd`).

Change these as appropriate for your system. As `sqltool.rc` contains credentials, be sure to lock down its permissions as you would for `~/SA.pwd`.